# Splitting a list into 2 lists at a pivot in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to split a list into 2 lists at a pivot P, if the number is less than P it goes into L1 and if it is greater than P then it will go into L2.

This is what I have so far, I am able to split a list L into L1 = [[],[]] in this form. But I want to split the list into 2 lists L1, and L2, how would I do that?

```
split(L,P,L1):-
   split(L,P,[],L1).

split([],_,[],[]).
split([],_,X,[X]) :- X \= [].
split([P|T],P,[],L1) :- split(T,P,[],L1).
split([P|T],P,L,[L|L1]) :- L \= [], split(T,P,[],L1).
split([H|T],P,S,L1) :- H \= P, append(S, [H], S2), split(T,P,S2,L1).
```

Comment: You should take a look a **partition/4**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need three rules to implement this predicate:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

split([], _, [], []).
split([H|T], P, L1, [H|T2]) :-
    H #>= P,
    split(T, P, L1, T2).
split([H|T], P, [H|T1], L2) :-
    H #< P,
    split(T, P, T1, L2).
```

The code is fairly straightforward

Note that, because of `library(clpfd)`, this predicate also works e.g. when the initial list and the pivot are not known:

```
?- split(L,P,[5,47],[101]).
L = [101, 5, 47],
P in 48..101 ;
L = [5, 101, 47],
P in 48..101 ;
L = [5, 47, 101],
P in 48..101 ;
false.
```

#### Using `partition/4`

As mentionned in a comment, you can use [`partition/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=partition/4) to do this:

```
split(L, P, L1, L2) :-
    partition(zcompare(>,P), L, L1, L2).
```

However, this will not exhibit as many different behaviours as the first implementation.

Comment: Using `partition/4` in combination with [tag:clpfd] gives logically unsound answers for many non-ground queries. Why not use `(>)/2` or, even better, `tpartition/4` in `library(reif)`?

Comment: is it possible to make it without using any library or built-in predicate?

Comment: @ScrappyMontana just remove the library call and replace `#>=` by `>=` and `#<` by `<`. You will lose some desirable behaviours though.

Comment: @Fatalize what desirable behaviours are lost by not using the library?

Comment: @ScrappyMontana It will work for what you want but won't e.g. when the first argument is not known